# String interpolation with Python AND Javascript from server to client

Tags: javascript, python, string, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to pass a string to be interpolated to Javascript coming from Python?

For example, to string interpolate a Python string, I `f-strings` like so

```
>>> friend = "Bob"
>>> f"Hey there, {friend}"
Hey there, Bob
```

However, I want to send a string that the client (Javascript code) can also string interpolate.

```
friend1 = "Bob"
friend2 = "Jill"
f"Hi here {friend}! When are you going to the {LOCATION}? {friend2} is going at 8AM."
```

In the example above, I only want to fill in the values for `friend1` and `friend2` but I want `LOCATION` to be filled in by the client.

Comment: Are you looking for [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals?#string_interpolation) ?

Comment: It might also be helpful to know that to get a `{` in an f-string one would escape it with a second `{`... ie:  `f"I am at {{ LOCATION }}."`

Comment: @JonSG This is what I was looking for. Thank you! Please reply with an answer and I will gladly accept it

Answer (score 0):

[replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) seems to be the easiest option

```js
const text = "Hi here Bob! When are you going to the {LOCATION}? Jill is going at 8AM."
const result = text.replace('{LOCATION}', 'cinema')
console.log(result)
```